Generating EF6 migrations with Npgsql
I am trying to set up my project to use EF6 in conjunction with Npgsql. However I am having trouble with generating the relevant sql migrations. I am new to PostgreSQL so chances are I am missing something obvious.
I am following this guide to get started, but I find it is not too richly documented.
What I am working with:

EF6.4.4 (unfortunately I cannot use EFCore)
net4.8 (same, cannot use Core)
EntityFrmawork6.Npgsql 6.4.3
Npgsql 4.1.3

app.config
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
               <add name="DbContext" connectionString="{myConnectionString}" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>      
      <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>

DbConfiguration class
public class NpgSqlConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public NpgSqlConfiguration()
    {
        var name = "Npgsql";

        SetProviderFactory(providerInvariantName: name,
                           providerFactory: NpgsqlFactory.Instance);

        SetProviderServices(providerInvariantName: name,
                            provider: NpgsqlServices.Instance);

        SetMigrationSqlGenerator(name, () => new SqlGenerator());

        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(connectionFactory: new NpgsqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}
public class SqlGenerator : NpgsqlMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    // should something happen here?
}

All of that setup results in generating this type of sql migration, which would not work on a postgresql database because of the square brackets; column types etc
C# migration (EF6)
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.adres",
        c => new
            {
                id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
                straat = c.String(),
                huisnummer = c.Int(nullable: false),
                toevoegsel = c.String(),
                postcode = c.String(),
                woonplaats = c.String(),
                provincie = c.String(),
                land = c.String(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.id);

Sql script generated (EF6)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[adres] (
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT newsequentialid(),
    [straat] [nvarchar](max),
    [huisnummer] [int] NOT NULL,
    [toevoegsel] [nvarchar](max),
    [postcode] [nvarchar](max),
    [woonplaats] [nvarchar](max),
    [provincie] [nvarchar](max),
    [land] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.adres] PRIMARY KEY ([id])
)

Whereas if I was able to use EFCore I would have been able to generate the migrations as such, which work quite effortlessly
C# migration (EFCore)
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "adres",
        columns: table => new
        {
            id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
            straat = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
            huisnummer = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
            toevoegsel = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
            postcode = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
            woonplaats = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
            provincie = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
            land = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
            locatie = table.Column<Point>(type: "geometry", nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("pk_adres", x => x.id);
        });

Sql script generated (EFCore)
CREATE TABLE adres (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    straat text NOT NULL,
    huisnummer integer NOT NULL,
    toevoegsel text NULL,
    postcode text NOT NULL,
    woonplaats text NOT NULL,
    provincie text NOT NULL,
    land text NOT NULL,
    locatie geometry NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_adres PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

So my question is-

Is it possible to generate npgsql migrations with EF6 and net4.8?
Which part of my setup is incorrect or missing?

